# Использовать оператор ИЛИ вместо if

Tags: javascript

сделайте капризного робота, который в confirm спрашивает "шопинг?", а в случае отказа - выводить alert "ты - бяка".

```js
var answer = confirm("Shopping?");
answer && alert(":))") || answer && alert("You are a caca!!!");
```

Логический оператор ИЛИ выводит первое значение, равное true, а в моем случае идет дальше. Почему?

Answer (score 6):

Потому что `alert` ничего не возвращает.

```js
var answer = confirm("Shopping?");
answer && !alert(":))") || alert("You are a caca!!!");
```

Answer (score 4):

> Логический оператор ИЛИ выводит первое значение, равное true

В данном случае, первым операндом будет выражение

```
answer && alert(":))")
```

и так как `alert` возвращает `undefined`, значение выражения приводится к `false`, из-за этого идет вычисление второго аргумента